# running selenium test suites created by selenium ide (firefox) over command line (ubuntu)

Tags: firefox, selenium

I have the problem that my selenium tests created via the firefox plugin "Selenium IDE" won't work when executed over cli with htmlsuite command. The test should simply open google.de in firefox browser.
I can record and execute the test just fine in selenium ide, but when i execute the following command in cli:

```
java -jar /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/SuiteCRM_CI_Test/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -debug -log /home/jenkins/wtflog.log -firoxProfileTemplate /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/SuiteCRM_CI_Test/firefox_profile -htmlSuite *firefox http://google.de /home/koschig/Arbeitsfläche/seleniumtests/googlesuite.html results.html
```

All that happens is, firefox will be opened with 2 tabs: one being the firstrun" tab and the other is the following: 
`chrome://src/content/TestRunner.html?auto=true&multiWindow=true&defaultLogLevel=info&baseUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.de&resultsUrl=http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/postResults&test=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4444%2Fselenium-server%2Ftests%2Fgooglesuite.html`
which gets me an `error, file not found`

Well, I don't know where the first half of this url comes from, the second half is crafted with the parameters I wrote in the command line.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I expected that firefox will be opened and google.de will be accessed...